# How do we match a suffix in a string in bash?

Tags: bash, pattern-matching

I want to check if an input parameter ends with ".c"? How do I check that? Here is what I got so far (Thanks for your help):

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $@
do
    if [$i ends with ".c"]
    then
            echo "YES"
        fi
done
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A classical case for `case`!

```
case $i in *.c) echo Yes;; esac
```

Yes, the syntax is arcane, but you get used to it quickly. Unlike various Bash and POSIX extensions, this is portable all the way back to the original Bourne shell.

Answer (score 18):

```
$ [[ foo.c = *.c ]] ; echo $?
0
$ [[ foo.h = *.c ]] ; echo $?
1
```

Comment: I guess foo.c should be replaced by $i ?

Comment: Correct. Quotes aren't needed since `[[` knows what to do, unlike `[`.

Comment: "When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in Pattern Matching" - from https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 11):

```
for i in $@; do
    if [ -z ${i##*.c} ]; then
        echo "YES: $i"
    fi
done


$ ./test.sh .c .c-and-more before.c-and-after foo.h foo.c barc foo.C
YES: .c
YES: foo.c
$
```

Explanation (thanks to [jpaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712526/jpaugh)):

1. Iterate over command line arguments: `for i in $@; do`
2. Main trick is here: `if [ -z ${i##*.c} ]; then`. Here we check if length of string `${i##*.c}` is zero. `${i##*.c}` means: take $i value and remove substring by template "*.c". If result is empty string, then we have ".c" suffix.

Here if some additional info from man bash, section Parameter Expasion

```
${parameter#word}
${parameter##word}
    Remove matching prefix pattern.  The word is expanded to produce a pat‐
    tern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern matches the  begin‐
    ning of the value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the
    expanded value of parameter with the  shortest  matching  pattern  (the
    ``#''  case) or the longest matching pattern (the ``##'' case) deleted.
    If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal  operation  is  applied  to
    each  positional  parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
    list.  If parameter is an array variable subscripted with @ or  *,  the
    pattern  removal  operation  is  applied to each member of the array in
    turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```

Comment: Please explain your code. Try to look at it from a beginner's perspective. Someone who can understand it without explanation could have written it themselves.

Comment: For example, it's worth explaining the name of the `#` operator (so the OP can search for further documentation), and document the difference between `#` and `##`.

Comment: jpaugh, I've added explanation. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to seeing your future contributions to the site & community of SO.